# Warning message and URLs not found on menu items

Tags: 7

My question is in relation to a Mamp issue Im having.

Installed Mamp on my MacBook, loaded the database off my live Drupal 7 site, downloaded and copied the Drupal files on the live site to Mamp htdocs, changed the Drupal config settings (db, host, user, password) to use Mamp site, but it displays the home page, with the warning messages below, and if you click on any menu item it displays URL not found. Any ideas what Im doing wrong?

Ive tried using the latest Drupal 7 core, and also using the same Drupal files as the live site, but I get the same result.

Warning message on Home page:

```
Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". 
Did you      mean to use "continue 2"? in require_once() 
(line 341 of  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rltc/includes/module.inc).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning looks like a PHP incompatibility. So either fix the code that's been triggering it (and at best provide a patch for it on drupal.org) or change MAMP's PHP version. Probably to something lower as it is now.

The URL not found error looks like as if you misconfigured your `.htaccess` file. Ensure this file exists and maybe uncomment the following line.

```
RewriteBase /
```